# Unable to change appbar title visibility after it was initially set

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I am trying to show and hide appbar title depending on the state of CollapsingToolbarLayout.

[image]

I use this command:

```
(activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar?.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(show)
```

Seems it has no effect after appbar is set up. Is there a way to hide/show and change title runtime?

Comment: Use this `collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle("");`

Comment: It works. Thank you. Could you post it as answer, not comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle("");
```

Instead of

```
(activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar?.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(show)
```